# Eve: CRUD on field which is of list type

Tags: python, eve

Hi is there any workaround for reading/adding/modifying/deleting items from field which is list of dictionaries? I know that it's not currently supported by Eve so is here any recommendation?

To be more specific, here is my schema.

```
companies = {
    'employees': {
        'type': 'list',
        'schema': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'schema': {
                'user': {
                    'type': 'objectid',
                    'required': True,
                    'data_relation': {
                        'resource': 'users',
                        'field': '_id',
                    },
                },
                'role': {
                    'type': 'objectid',
                    'required': True,
                    'data_relation': {
                        'resource': 'company_roles',
                        'field': '_id',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do CRUD operations on employees. Any hints?